# Направление потока байтов из InputStream в OutputStream и наоборот

Tags: java, потоки-данных

Приветствую.
Ситуация вот какая. Данные приходят от модема в InputStream. Мне их надо на лету пускать в OutputStream. И обратная ситуация...
Увидел в документации такую милую вещь как PipedInputStream и PipedOutputStream. Которые стыкуются прямо в конструкторе их создания. Что вы о них думаете? Там ещё в доках написано, что не рекомендуется их оба использовать в одном thread из-за опасности deadlock. Но каков соблазн!))))
Вобщем, что вы думаете по поводу сабжа и piped?
Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эта штука внутри очень уродливо реализована. Вердикт: не использовать. Хотя бы потому, что нужно какой-то дополнительный поток запускать.. который ещё надо будет как-то уничтожать.

Просто копируйте байты и всё

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
int rc;
while ((rc = is.read(buffer)) != -1)
    os.write(buffer, 0, rc);
```