# Непонятный символ в тексте

Tags: java

Не могу понять от куда берется непонятный символ в тексте. Создал файл с таким содержимым:

```
Киев Нью-Йорк Амстердам Вена Мельбурн
```

Обрабатываю его таким вот кодом:

```
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("/home/sergei/file1.txt");

    char buff[] = new char[1024];
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    while (fileReader.read(buff) > 0) {
        stringBuilder.append(buff);
    }
    String strings[] = stringBuilder.toString().split("\\s");
    for (String string : strings) {
        System.out.println(string);
    }

    fileReader.close();
```

В конце выводится символ пустой символ (`""`). Не понимаю от куда он берется. Дебаггер показывает: `value = {char[986]@472}`.

***От куда берется этот злополучный символ ?*** Нет сил уже бороться с ним. Проверка типа `string == ""` не проходит.

Comment: В качестве рабочего костыля можно надо строкой trim() сделать

Comment: У Вас в файле в конце похоже перевод строки. Вот его read и читает в самом конце.

Comment: вы неправильно добавляете считанные данные в stringbuilder, `fileReader.read` возвращает, сколько реально было прочитано байт, а вы приклеиваете сразу весь массив, который скорее всего и до конца не заполнен, поэтому хвост вашей строки состоит из символов с кодом 0.

Comment: @zRrr почему байт ? Разве `FileReader` не наследуется от `Reader`  (через `InputStreamReader`), который работает с символами, а не байтами ? Покажите как правильно.

Comment: типовой способ переноса данных из входного в выходной поток - http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/18446/190934 . Для вашего случая просто `byte[]` -> `char[]` и `out.write` -> `stringBuilder.append`